# Python - Pseudocode to decrypt a XOR encrypted string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, xor

I'm trying to solve this challenge and having some trouble. First, I'm not super familiar with XOR. I understand that XOR is symmetric so all I need to do to decrypt this string is encrypt it again with the same key, which I have.

I don't want an answer handed to me, so if possible can someone assist with kickstarting my brain with some pseudocode on how you would create a Python script to take a users input, and decrypt their XOR encrypted string?

Comment: Show us what you've attempted so far - do you know how to simply XOR two numbers together?  Do you know how to convert a character to a number and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain it this way.

```
XOR table
=========
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
```

So, imagine a binary number

10110011

And, you have a key

11001100

If you XOR them you get:

01111111

With me? Now, XOR the encrypted number with the key, and you return back to original.

10110011

Here is some pseudo-code as well for this. It is a heavy to demonstrate the work.

```
Get the input-string from user
Get the encrypt-key from user     #Assume it is also a string;

Loop through the input-string character by character
    Convert character to its binary representation as a string
    Concatenate that to input-string-converted-to-binary string

Loop through the encrypt-key character by character
    Convert character to its binary representation as a string
    Concatenate that to encrypt-key-converted-to-binary string

Get the length of the encrypt-key-converted-to-binary string
Calculate totalloops by dividing that into the length of the input-string-converted-to-binary string

Loop for totalloops
    Loop for each character in the subsection of the input-string-converted-to-binary string
        Calculate XOR of the digit
        Concatenate into encrypted-value string
```

You now have the binary string. You can reverse the process of converting the binary string into characters. But, you may get unprintable characters, which is why doing it the long way gives you more to inspect.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense. I found some example code here which basically achieves what you had laid out. https://www.abhishekshukla.com/python/adventures-in-cryptography-with-python-xor-cipher/

Comment: Glad I could give you something that helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
user_number = input("Enter your number")

if( user_number. isdigit()):

print("User input is Number ")
else:

print("User input is string ")
```

because its two inputs cannot be unambiguously reconstructed
from its single output.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have to do with XOR though. That basically just determines if a users input is an integer or a string it seems.